# Watchpoint in cortex M4

Tags: c, arm, breakpoints, cortex-m, watchpoint

I have a global constant array `const uint32_t p[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`. I have made it read-protected by

```
     DWT->COMP1 = (uint32_t)&p;
     DWT->MASK1 = 6;
     DWT->FUNCTION1 = (1 << 11)| (1 << 0) | (1 << 2);
```

When I access the array members using a for loop, interrupt is generated 5 times and is exactly what I want.

```
for(int i= 0; i<5; i++){
    printf("p[%d] = %d\t",i,p[i]);
}
```

However, When I try to access the variables using a simple print statement without any loop

```
printf("p[0] = %d\t", p[0]);
```

, DebugMon_interrupt is not generated. This behaviour is quite weird.

If I remove the const keyword from the array, then it works fine i.e interrupt is generated both with and without loop while accessing the array elements.

Comment: Have you looked at the compiled code? I would assume in the single `printf` the compiler has replaced the `p[0]` with the value `1`

Comment: Yep check the assembly, or compile without optimizations -O0 in gcc.

Comment: You can force reads (at least with gcc) by declaring the array `const volatile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet @Colin is right. This happens because of code optimization during compilation.

Not sure about your particular scenario, but you can try to inform compiler to skip optimizations for a specified code block:

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")

printf("p[0] = %d\t", p[0]);

#pragma GCC pop_options
```

**Edit:**

I missed the fact the array is `const`. Obviously, in this case compiler will use hard-coded values. As per comments below, solution is to remove `const` (and possibly remove compiler optimizations as well).

Comment: Changing optimizations to -O0 didn't help. I think there is something with the const keyword, because when I make the array non-const it work fine.

Comment: When you remove the const qualifier, the compiler has to assume the value can change, and must therefore be read, rather than substituted with the value at compile time.

Comment: Ah, `const`... Sure. In this case compiler will just use hardcoded value.

Comment: Thanks @Colin, now I understood the cause.